# Using a timer to auto click a button when it runs out?

Tags: java, swing, button, timer

I have two buttons, one to ignore and one to fight a crime. I want to give the user 10 seconds to make a choice. If they fail to do so in 10 seconds, I want ignore to autoclick and execute the code. How do I go about doing this? I have struggled to get timers working.

Comment: You haven't even told us what GUI you are using, what exactly you are using to give the user those buttons, and what you tried and where it failed. How are we supposed to help you based on so little information?

Comment: learn about `javax.swing.Timer`.... it may help you..

Answer (score 1):

There is a `javax.swing.Timer` class in java.
It will execute the events after some time given when creating object of `Timer` class.. It is in milliseconds.

and you also have to provide the `ActionListener` for the event.

```
       // javax.swing.Timer(timeAfterWhichExecuteTheEventInMilliseconds, ListenerForTheEvent)
       javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                your_button.doClick();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on how your code will solve the problem ? As a piece of code with no explanation is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I will make a thread launched when screen is loaded:

```
//class creation
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        //disable the button that the user has to press
        button.setEnable(false);

        //add what you want to show to make him know that he loose
        //so execute your code or call a function
    }
}

//On your main class execution, do the following when screen loaded
MyThread timerThread = new MyThread();
timerThread.execute();
//continue with your code
```